# How to navigate back in history with Nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have a test that clicks some links that navigate the browser in a single-page-application. In the test, I want the browser to go back to the original page, and then assert that the state is correct.

How can I make Nightwatch go back as if it clicked the back button in the browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple `client.back()` should work, as documented in the [API/Protocol](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#protocol) reference.

Comment: `back()` is documented in the [protocol commands](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#protocol) section.

Comment: Thx for getting back on this by the way